# how do i send keystrokes to only one program?

Tags: c++, winapi, sendkeys

i have been having a hard time to find anything that is usefull but i found someone asked how to do that,([How to send keystrokes to a window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113950/how-to-send-keystrokes-to-a-window))

if used the code and i can set notepad's text but i want to send keys but sets the text, i
want to send keys like keybd_event i have been using it but i want to only have it send to one program.

```
keybd_event('a', NULL, NULL, NULL);  
keybd_event('a', NULL, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, NULL);
```

how could i do that?

Comment: I have added the win32/windows tag. If windows is not the OS, please re-edit to update the right one.

Comment: (1) Do you need to be able to send to any program at all, or do you have a particular set of programs in mind?  (2) Have you looked at AutoHotKey?  It's a standalone app (so no C++ interface) but it is often used to perform this kind of task.

Comment: moron: xD tyvm for adding the tag sorry i did not think of it.

jdigital: just the program i choose by the handle.
autoHotkey i have not looked at but there has to be someway i can send it to only one program.
my program is just a console window i don't really care about the window because it does nothing, i might just hide it but idk.

Comment: Does the program accept input on stdin?  If so, then instead of sending keystrokes, you may be able to pipe in your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to make a window have the focus before sending your keys. Look at [`FindWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499(VS.85).aspx) and [`SetForegroundWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633539(VS.85).aspx).

Something like this should work:

```
SetForegroundWindow(FindWindow(0,"Untitled - Notepad"));
keybd_event(....);
```

If instead you're talking about changing a window's text directly, look at [`GetWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633515(VS.85).aspx) to navigate the window tree and [`SendMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950(VS.85).aspx) with a [`WM_SETTEXT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632644(VS.85).aspx) parameter.