# Saving two data files from two two different applications at the same instant of time

Tags: c++, matlab

I have two separate applications giving me the option to click on "save data" and retrieve the data from that. But the data is saved for that instant of time only. As the engineering requires, I need the data from both the application simultaneously for that instant of time. I possess good knowledge in C++ and MATLAB. But I am no expert. Is there a way that I can go abouit this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to automate clicking on the buttons? Or modify the programs to talk to each other?

Comment: Yes, I would like to write my own program which could help me click on the save button of the applications simultaneously. For example, you can think of Microsoft Word and Paint. When I click on save on either of them, the other one should also get saved. These are not the two applications, I want to work with but just an example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355286/programmatically-mouse-click-in-another-window or https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

Comment: Do the programs have some keyboard shortcuts? Saving often is Ctrl+S. That would make a solution less relying on screen and window sizes. You will have to invoke the command for each window of the target programs. This should give some hints: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113950/how-to-send-keystrokes-to-a-window

Comment: Thank you @AlanBirtles. The one you sent me is in C# right?

Comment: @AlexGeorg no, there are no keyboard shortcuts to save them. But thank you, I will go through your attachment.

Comment: Yes its c# but the windows APIs you need are the same